# recibir datos de una actividad a otra automaticamente

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Tengo una activity y una ventana PopUp que sale al dar cick en un boton, esta ventana a su vez tiene un boton, el cual detecto su click desde la clase de la ventana, lo que hace el boton es pasarle unos datos a la actividad principal y cerrar el popup con el metodo finish(); Hasta ahi bien, el problema es que no se de que forma recibir los datos en el activity principal. Necesito que los datos (que son Strings )que el popup envia sean recibidos por la actividad principal (una vez cerrarda la ventana popup) y se pasen a un TextView de dicha actividad, todo de forma automatica.

PD: Cuando hago el Intent en el onClick del boton del PopUp, no uso el startActivity(intent); por que de ese modo se reinicia la actividad prinicipal, por lo cual solo le doy finish(); al PopUp y se cierra.

OnClick del boton del PopUp:

```
public void guardar2(View view){
    Intent intent= new Intent (this, Activity1.class);
    intent.putExtra("asunto",edit_asunto.getText());
    intent.putExtra("usuario",edit_usuario.getText());
    intent.putExtra("contra",edit_contra.getText());
    intent.putExtra("id",ID);
    finish();
}
```

No se que método utilizar para que la Activity1 reciba los datos y los almacene en un TextView (Todo automáticamente sin necesidad de tocar otro botón).

Comment: cuando presiones el botón del popup quieres que mande los datos mainactivity?

Comment: @junior Exacto, aunque en mi caso se llama Activiy1. y que sin necesidad de presionar otro boton del activity, los datos recibidos (texto) tomen lugar en un text view de ese activity

Comment: Valen W si puedes porfa respondete yo ya intente de todo, logre una que sale advertencia porque consume memoria, pero no se cuéntame y la coloco, el problema radica en que no se puede obtener el contexto de la actividad que inicia el intent

Comment: @junior ya logré solucionarlo de cierta manera. los TextView se cambian (En la clase del popup )antes de que el PopUp se cierre. Para eso tuve que poner Activity1.txt_asunto.setText(blablabla); y para que no me de error tuve que hacerlo static al textview, ¿eso me afecta en algo?

Comment: solo consume memoria, pero por las pruebas que hice maximo 2MB solo  muestran la advertencia las versiones anteriores al 2.3.2 de android studio

Comment: Bueno pues muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `Activity1` obtenemos los extras y los asignamos al texto, para eso, primero debemos obtener el intent que lanzo esa activity para obtener los extras que le pasas desde MainActivity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

y luego solo obtienes los valores

```
String asunto = intent.getStringExtra("asunto");
String usuario = intent.getStringExtra("usuario");
String contra = intent.getStringExtra("contra");
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

y se lo asignamos a algun textView

```
txtView.setText(asunto);
txtView2.setText(usuario);
txtView3.setText(contra);
txtView4.setText(id);
```

Para hacerlo con una buena practica, podes chequear que los extras sean distinto de null para que no tengas un `NullPointerException` si los valores que estas pasando no existen.

En **Activity1**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String asunto,usuario,contra,id;

if (extras != null) {
    asunto = extras.getString("asunto");
    usuario = extras.getString("usuario");
    contra = extras.getString("contra"); 
    id = extras.getString("id");
}
```

luego lo asignas igual

```
    txtView.setText(asunto);
    txtView2.setText(usuario);
    txtView3.setText(contra);
    txtView4.setText(id);
```

Cualquiera de los dos sirve, pero te recomiendo usar la ultima opcion para chequear por posibles null

Comment: Gracias, me sirve, aunque sigo con una duda, si quiero que todo eso se haga de forma automática al cerrar el PopUp, que debería hacer?  (Ya lo probé en el onCreate() pero no funciona)

Comment: hay que tener el contexto del Activity1 para ejecutarle un metodo